# Full calendar in JSP Servlet (using MVC) get records from MySQL returns NULL

Tags: jsp, servlets, calendar

I am trying to use Full calendar jquery plugin with jsp, servlet (MVC) for the first time.

Can get all working with the following in the Servlet:

```
 List allClassesList = new ArrayList();
 TTSlotDB slot1 = new TTSlotDB();

 slot1.setId(1);
 slot1.setTitle("WORK");
 slot1.setStart("2017-01-08");
 allClassesList.add(slot1);


TTSlotDB slot2 = new TTSlotDB();
slot2.setId(2);
slot2.setTitle("REST");
slot2.setStart("2017-01-25");
allClassesList.add(slot2);

String json = new Gson().toJson(allClassesList);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
//System.out.println("HELLO AGAIN"+json);
```

I am stuck if I try to get all lessons timetable from MySQL. I am using MVC. In Servlet for now is:

```
      TTSlotDB slot = new TTSlotDB();
      Collection<TTSlotDB> timetable = new ArrayList< TTSlotDB>();     
      timetable = slot.displayTimetable();

     String json = new Gson().toJson(timetable);
     response.setContentType("application/json");
     response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
     response.getWriter().write(json);
```

The approach above does not bring events to full calendar view. Json returns NULL in

```
System.out.println(json);
```

TTSlotDB:

```
    public Collection<TTSlotDB> displayTimetable() throws SQLException {
    Collection<TTSlotDB> timetable = new ArrayList<TTSlotDB>();

    ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
    Connection connection = pool.getConnection();

    Statement st = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;


    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ttslot";

    ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);



    try {
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {

            TTSlotDB tt = new TTSlotDB();
            tt.setId(rs.getInt("ttId"));
            tt.setStart(rs.getString("start"));
            tt.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));

            timetable.add(tt);
          }
           return timetable;

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closeStatement(st);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);

    }
}
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was in a query

```
while (rs.next()) {

        TTSlotDB tt = new TTSlotDB();
        tt.setId(rs.getInt("ttId"));
        tt.setStart(rs.getString("start"));
        tt.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));

        timetable.add(tt);
      }
```

There instead of

```
tt.setId(rs.getInt("ttId"));
```

Should be

```
tt.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
```

as column name in database itself is "id", not "ttId"